# How to manage internal configuration settings for a Java library?

Tags: java, configuration

I'm developing a Java library that can be used within Android, Web and Desktop apps. The library consists of a few mostly separated modules that share common configuration settings (e.g. 'enabled', 'api key').

**The Goal**

The config should allow changes at runtime *(e.g. API, JMX or SharedPreferemes in Android)* without compromising portability *(e.g. no database)*, testability or thread-safety (some modules run in a separate thread).

**Approach**

What I am currently using is a *config object* that I create at startup and pass to the various modules (which themselves pass it to sub classes). Each class then copies the fields it needs to a local field - the only problem: Settings cannot be changed at runtime.

Other ideas:

- using *static*: hard to test
- passing *references* to modules: thread-safe?

**What's the best solution / best practice here?**

---

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear, a module does not need to know if a change was made to the config, it should simply use the field's new value directly and work with it from then on.

Comment: I had another idea myself: by wrapping each config field in a ConfigItem<T> I could create an AndroidConfigItem<T> that wraps each get() checking if the SharedPreferences have changed, thoughts?

Comment: I thought about it, looked at the source code of ehcache to see how they do it and came to the conclusion that Óscar's concept (Observer pattern) is the best approach for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Do not copy the fields each class needs to a local field; always access the properties from the config object (any cache-management should be done on the config object)
- Make sure that none of the classes that use the config object modify it *directly* in any way (by inserting, deleting keys or changing its values)
- Pre-load all the information you need in the config-object at instantiation time
- Make the config object a Singleton, and share it among the needed clients
- Provide a mechanism for the config object to evict any cache entries that are no longer valid
- Use the Observer pattern to keep the cache up to date

Comment: thanks for your suggestions - one question, when you say "share it among the needed clients", do you mean storing a reference to it?

Comment: Yes, in that way all the clients of the configuration object will see the same up-to-date information